# Determine if any two strings in a list start with the same character functionally

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically, I want this to be `False`:

```
('click', 'bait', 'carrot', 'juice')
```

And this to be `True`, because every string starts with a different character than the others:

```
('click', 'bait', 'juice', 'silly')
```

The closest I've gotten is the following, but it doesn't look very nice at all.

```
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: (y, x[0] != y[0]), map(operator.itemgetter(0), ('click', 'bait', 'carrot', 'juice')))[1]
```

It fails because it only checks strings that lie next to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = ('click', 'bait', 'carrot', 'juice')

len(set(w[0] for w in data)) == len(data)
# -> False
```

Comment: I like this best, it's so simple!

Answer (score 2):

I assume by functional you mean no state mutation.

```
any(n > 1 for n in collections.Counter(s[0] for s in ('click', 'bait', 'carrot', 'juice')).values())
```

Comment: It's not strictly "functional", though...?

Comment: @Tomalak how so?

Comment: Functional in terms of *"applying a reducer to the input for an overall result of True or False"*.

Comment: @Tomalak and what is a reducer?

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. A pure function that calculates an output value from two input values, with the first input value type matching the function's return type. (My solution is not functional either.)

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
l=('click', 'bait', 'carrot', 'juice')
def f(l):
    s=set()
    for i in l:
        if i[0] in s:
            return False
        s.add(i[0])
    return True
```

The set `s` consists of the first letters that were seen so far. At each iteration you move to the next word and check whether the first letter is in `s`. If it is there, you return `False`. Otherwise, you add the first letter to `s` and continue. The advantage of the loop is that if a first letter repeats early you stop the iterations and do not proceed. Thus avoiding unnecessary work.